# Get's records where gap between two dates is less than or equal to 5 days

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables: tickets with unique ticket id and tickethistory with multiple records of a ticket (like open,attend,forward,close etc). Want to get records of
customers whose current ticket is open and last closed ticket is within 5 days gap. Using following query gives multiple records of closed tickets. Want last closed ticket actiondate in order to calculate days gap. If current open ticket and last closed ticket are within 5 days gap, want to consider current ticket as repeated.

```
SELECT A.ticketId,A.username,A.status,A.areaName,A.subject
,d.deptId,d.action,d.actionDate odate,g.actionDate cdate,g.status 
FROM tb_tickets A
INNER JOIN (SELECT action, actiondate, ticketId, deptId FROM tb_ticketHistory WHERE action='Open') d
on a.ticketId = d.ticketid
INNER JOIN (SELECT th.ticketid, tt.username, tt.status, actiondate FROM tb_ticketHistory th 
INNER JOIN tb_tickets tt 
on th.ticketId = tt.ticketId WHERE th.action='closed') g
on a.username = g.username
WHERE d.deptId=5 AND a.status!='closed'
ORDER BY ticketId ASC
```

Comment: can you please share the sample records from the input tables with create table script and the expected output.

Comment: Use `datediff` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you haven't give exact structure and sample data, it's tough to give an exact answer. but you can try following code by tweaking it as your structure -

```
select CurrentOpenTickets.customerid, CurrentOpenTickets.ticketid from
(
select customerid, t.ticketid, actiondate from [dbo].[tb_ticketHistory ] th
inner join [dbo].[tb_Tickets] t on t.ticketid = th.ticketid
where t.status != 'C'
) CurrentOpenTickets
inner join 
(select customerid, t.ticketid, actiondate from [dbo].[tb_ticketHistory ] th
inner join [dbo].[tb_Tickets] t on t.ticketid = th.ticketid
where th.status = 'C'
) PastClosedTickets

on CurrentOpenTickets.customerid = PastClosedTickets.customerid and datediff(DAY, CurrentOpenTickets.actiondate, PastClosedTickets.actiondate) <= 5
```

Comment: Yes. This worked with some minor changes:

select cot.uid, cot.ticketid, cot.status, cot.actionDate,
pct.uid, pct.ticketId,  pct.status, pct.actionDate from
(
select top 1 uid, t.ticketid, actiondate, t.status from tb_ticketHistory th
inner join tb_Tickets t on t.ticketid = th.ticketid
where t.status != 'Closed' and uid='xyz'
) Cot
right join 
(select top 1 uid, t.ticketid, actiondate, t.status from tb_ticketHistory th
inner join tb_Tickets t on t.ticketid = th.ticketid
where t.status = 'Closed' and uid='xyz' order by ticketId DESC
) Pct
on cot.uid = pct.uid